# "make" command for Makefile no longer works after upgrading to ventura

Tags: makefile, macos-ventura

I use a makefile in all my applications spanning across multiple languages as a uniform way of booting up my apps

for whatever reason OSX Ventura broke the command "make"

```bash
$ make dev
make dev
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

```
dev:
    yarn run dev
```

Edit

running the following command reveals where make is installed

```
 $ which make
/usr/bin/make
```

make is a binary file while does not allow me to open

running `yarn run dev` on its own works just fine

Comment: Does that path exist?  Have you figured out what's trying to execute xcrun?

Comment: Duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Comment: ill give re installing `xcode-select --install` a shot

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Comment: resolved  xcode-select --install worked

Comment: `xcode-select --install` doesn't work for me